window.location.href.match not working for homepage
I'm creating an eshop on one eCommerce platform (Shoptet) a I'm trying to hide few elements only on homepage but I still want to see them on subpages. These elements have same classes.
My script looks like this:
<script>
var home = "^https://<siteid>.myshoptet.com$"
if (window.location.href.match(home)) {
    $('.detail-parameters').hide();
    $('.availability-value').hide();
    $('.add-to-cart').hide();
}
</script>

It's not working but when I put negation into condition (!window.location.href.match(home)) it works beautifully for subpages.
Any advices how to make it work only on homepage? The URL is real URL of eshop.
Thank you!

window.location.pathname === '/'

Go to your shop's homepage, and execute console.log(location.href) via the browser console - you will see, that the URL is actually https://644859.myshoptet.com/ (The browser address bar does not necessarily always show you the full, actual URL - the trailing slash is often not shown when you are at the domain root, and some browsers even hide query string parameters from the user by default.)

"^https://644859.myshoptet.com$" is just a string, if you need to match with a regular expression, surround it with a slash and scape the special characters with backslash.
var home = /^https:\/\/644859\.myshoptet\.com$/
if (window.location.href.match(home)) {
    $('.detail-parameters').hide();
    $('.availability-value').hide();
    $('.add-to-cart').hide();
}

Keep in mind that window.location.href could end with slash at the end like https://644859.myshoptet.com/ as @CBroe mentioned
So the safer check is using startsWith method or just remove the dollar sign at the end of your regular expression.
var home = /^https:\/\/644859\.myshoptet\.com/
if (window.location.href.match(home)) {
  // ...code
}

var home = "https://644859.myshoptet.com"
if (window.location.href.startsWith(home)) {
  // ...code
}


window.location.href can include query strings and hashes so it might not match correctly using === or a $ in the regex

@Reyno, I just realized that and I'm updating my answer, thanks.

thank you for your help guys but none of those working for me. i also tried to combinate somehow what you mentioned but still without desired result.

you are hardcoding that pathname but here you are trying to math the pathname for the home , and it could change from https or http or wherever it is , so you should use regular expressions and avoid hardcoding the pathname
so you new code would be like this .
<script>
var homeRegex = /^https:\/\/644859\.myshoptet\.com\/?$/; // Regular expression to match the homepage URL

if (homeRegex.test(window.location.href)) {
    $('.detail-parameters').hide();
    $('.availability-value').hide();
    $('.add-to-cart').hide();
}
</script>

let me also break down to you this regular expression
the ^ and the $ are to make sure that the pathname match the start and end of the URL, ensuring an exact match.
/? matches an optional trailing slash after the domain , so you should be careful using it , you should remove if you only the exact path '/'
you will remove it in case you dont want to have the optional trailing in the pathname .
using this approach allows you to use regular expressions to match the homepage URL more flexibly

thank you for your help and also for explaining it to me but it's still not working.
